# Variance comparison of $XY$ and $\min(X,Y)$

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance

There are two independent random variables and each is Gaussian with $\mathrm{E}(X)=mx, \mathrm{E}(Y)=my$, variance of X, i.e. $\mathrm{Var}(X)=vx, \mathrm{Var}(Y)=vy$, respectively. I would like to compare the magnitudes of variances of two functions of these random variables, i.e., $X\times Y$ and $\min(X,Y)$.
I tried hard to compute the variances of these two functions of random variables, and failed. I just need to show variance of $XY$ is greater than or equal to the variance of $\min(X,Y)$, i.e., $\mathrm{Var}(XY) \geq \mathrm{Var}(\min(X,Y))$.
I would really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: When, 0 < {wa1, wa2, wb1, wb2}  < 1 ,

wa = [ wa1 wa2];    % where wa1+wa2 = 1;

wb = [ wb1 wb2];     % where  wb1+wb2 = 1;

 

wp = wa.*wb;   % i.e., wp = [wa1*wb1 wa2*wb2];

wp1 = wp(1);

wp2 = wp(2);

 

w1 = wp1/sum(wp);

w2 = wp2/sum(wp);

 

w = [w1 w2];    % i.e.,  w1+w2 = 1

 

 

wp_mm = [min(wa1,wb1) min(wa2,wb2)];

 

wp1_mm = wp_mm(1);

wp2_mm = wp_mm(2);

 

w1_mm = wp1_mm/sum(wp_mm);

w2_mm = wp2_mm/sum(wp_mm);

 

w_mm = [w1_mm w2_mm];  % i.e., w1_mm+w2_mm = 1

 

Above is satisfied, prove the below.

var(w) > = var(w_mm)

Answer (score 2):

It is good that you have not succeeded, **because the relation is not true:** sometimes the variance of $\min(X,Y)$ exceeds the variance of $XY.$

Consider what happens to these two variances when any two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are simultaneously multiplied by a positive number $\lambda:$ because $XY$ is multiplied by $\lambda^2,$ its variance is multiplied by $(\lambda^2)^2 = \lambda^4,$ but because the smaller of $X$ and $Y$ is multiplied by $\lambda,$ its variance is multiplied by $\lambda^2.$  Thus, assuming the ratio

$$f_{X,Y} = \frac{\operatorname{Var}(\min(X,Y))}{\operatorname{Var}(XY)}$$

exists, it is multiplied by $\lambda^{-2}.$

*You are hoping to show that $f_{X,Y} \lt 1$ no matter what (Gaussian) distributions $X$ and $Y$ might have.*

By selecting $\lambda \lt \sqrt{f_{X,Y}},$ chosen to assure $\lambda^{-2} \gt 1/f_{X,Y},$ you will change the ratio to

$$f_{\lambda X, \lambda Y} = \frac{\operatorname{Var}(\min(\lambda X,\lambda Y))}{\operatorname{Var}(\lambda^2XY)} = \lambda^{-2}f_{X,Y} \gt \left(\frac{1}{f_{X,Y}}\right) f_{X,Y} = 1.$$

**The pair $\lambda X, \lambda Y$ provides a counterexample** to what you want to prove provided $f_{X,Y}$ is nonzero, because the new variables $\lambda X$ and $\lambda Y$ are still independent with Gaussian distributions.

---

Notice that the only assumption about the random variables $(X,Y)$ needed to construct this counterexample was that $\operatorname{Var}(XY)\ne 0$ and $\operatorname{Var}(\min(X,Y))\ne 0.$  Both of these are (obviously) the case when $(X,Y)$ has a nondegenerate bivariate Gaussian distribution.

Comment: Great, but could you prove that Var(min(lambdaX,lambdaY))=lambda^(2)Var(min(X,Y)) while Var(lambda^(2)XY) = lambda^(4)Var(XY) is true.

Comment: This is a basic property of variances, readily demonstrated from any definition of variance you might want to use.

Comment: It might be a basic property, but I have never seen anywhere, so if you can show me any link for the references, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134769 for instance.

Comment: I know this but this is not the right reference to show Var(min(lambdaX,lambdaY))=lambda^(2)Var(min(X,Y)). This is a variance of minimum of two functions. I don't think it can be obtained in linear.

Comment: It will be hard to find a reference because that's just a matter of algebra: when $x$ and $y$ are any numbers and $\lambda\gt 0,$ $\min(\lambda x, \lambda y) = \lambda\min(x,y).$ For some intuition, it helps to recognize that multiplying by $\lambda$ is tantamount to changing the units of measurement in which $X$ and $Y$ are expressed.  The units of $\min(X,Y)$ are the same as the common units of $X$ and $Y,$ but the units of $XY$ are *squared* units. This shows you are attempting to compare two incommensurable things, such as length and area.  That's why there's no universal inequality.

Comment: Oh, I see. Now I understand, many thanks, then how about the following example? I would like to prove it when the number is greater than 2 while the example is describing when the elements are only two. please see my added comment.